# PHP How do I find the number of days until the next January 1 (without specifying the year)?

Tags: php, date

How do I find out the number of days until the next January 1 without specifying a year?

I always want to know how many days until the next January 1, so I don't want to say "how many until Jan 1, 2020" or I'll need to reset my variable every year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects to do the math. Create one object which is today, and another which is `January 1`, to which we then add a year, and then take the difference:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$jan1 = new DateTime('January 1');
$jan1->modify('+1 year');
$days = $today->diff($jan1)->days;
echo "$days days until January 1\n";
```

Output (on December 6)

```
25 days until January 1
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WltoH)